# Protect plesk gui 11.5.30 with a "basic auth" box?

Tags: nginx, plesk

Is it possible to protect plesk panel 11.5.30 GUI with a basic auth protection?

11.5.30 use as internal web server nginx. I founded this file: 
/etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/server.conf

but its not allowed to edit:

`ATTENTION!
DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.`

Have here anyone a simple example to add basic auth to plesk **GUI**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way (original posted by [SergeyUgdyzhekov](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?291451-Protect-plesk-panel-11-5-with-htaccess%28auth-basic%29&p=702210&viewfull=1#post702210))

```
# Create /etc/sw-cp-server/conf.d/protect-plesk.inc with content:
location / {
auth_basic "Restricted";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/sw-cp-server/conf.d/passwd;
}

# Generate passwd file
htpasswd -c /etc/sw-cp-server/conf.d/passwd admin

# Set correct permissions:
chown sw-cp-server:psaadm /etc/sw-cp-server/conf.d/passwd
chmod 640 /etc/sw-cp-server/conf.d/passwd

# Restart panel web server
/etc/init.d/sw-cp-server restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Plesk panel server's config stored in /etc/sw-cp-server/conf.d/plesk.conf

This config /etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/server.conf it's a config of public web server on port 80.